# How to combine 3 separate SQL statements into 1 set of results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL query that I am running 3 times (3 changing only the date range) and want to combine the result into one table, instead of running 3 different queries and trying to join outside of SQL. I am trying to find amount of times something has occurred per day/month/year. I'm running this in SQL Server.

I have 2 tables; one has the date of the transaction, and the other has the information I need (first 3 characters of the `InventoryNumber` table) so I am having to join these tables. I then want to group by the first 3 characters of the inventory number, and add the count in the column.

The end goal is to have something that looks like this:

```
InvNum | DayCount | MonthCount | YearCount
abc    | 2        | 10         | 40
def    | 0        | 2          | 6
xyz    | 0        | 0          | 2
```

Here is my query for the single day one. This works exactly like I want it to.  But now, I want to add on there the counts for the Month, and then the counts for the year also. The only thing that would change between this query and the other 2 is the count column name, and then the date.:

```
SELECT 
    LEFT(LINEITEM.InventoryNumber, 3) AS InvNum, 
    COUNT(*) AS DailyCount
FROM
    INVOICE
INNER JOIN  
    LINEITEM ON INVOICE.InvoiceID = LINEITEM.InvoiceID
WHERE
    InventoryNumber IS NOT Null
    AND InventoryNumber != 'Misc'
    AND DateCreated > '5-20-2022'
GROUP BY 
    LEFT(LINEITEM.InventoryNumber, 3)
ORDER BY 
    InvNum ASC;
```

I have looked through some of the other questions similar to this, but their queries were much simpler and I was not able to replicate the same thing with my queries.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using each instance of the query as a subquery and JOIN them all together? All 3 queries have the same key in common ```InvNum```, so you could join between em and create what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: No need to do `InventoryNumber IS NOT Null` since `InventoryNumber != 'Misc'` is true only for non-null InventoryNumber values.

Comment: Looking at the query again, is it really working for COUNTs with zero ocurrencies?

Comment: @ThomasDoconski I am not exactly sure how to do that. Still relatively new to SQL.

Comment: @ThomasDoconski When there are 0 occurrences, there is nothing for the table. So obviously the year table will have the most, then the month table, and the day table will have the least matches. But I want to join these tables.

Comment: What does month and year mean in this context? Is it a different start date?

Comment: @Charlieface I am trying to sum the current days stats, the previous 30 days stats, and then the previous 365 days stats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need conditional aggregation with three different start dates.

```sql
DECLARE @D date = '2022-05-20';
DECLARE @M date = '2022-04-21';
DECLARE @Y date = '2021-05-21';

SELECT InvNum     = LEFT(li.InventoryNumber, 3)
      ,DayCount   = COUNT(CASE WHEN i.DateCreated >= @D THEN 1 END)
      ,MonthCount = COUNT(CASE WHEN i.DateCreated >= @M THEN 1 END)
      ,YearCount  = COUNT(*)
 FROM INVOICE i
INNER JOIN LINEITEM li ON i.InvoiceID = li.InvoiceID
WHERE li.InventoryNumber <> 'Misc'
  AND i.DateCreated >= @Y
GROUP BY
  LEFT(li.InventoryNumber, 3)
ORDER BY
  InvNum;
```

> Note that `<> 'Misc'` also excludes nulls, and that `ASC` is the default.

You can also calculate those start dates dynamically

```sql
DECLARE @D date = DATEADD(day, -1, CAST(GETDATE() AS date));
DECLARE @M date = DATEADD(month, -1, CAST(GETDATE() AS date));
DECLARE @Y date = DATEADD(year, -1, CAST(GETDATE() AS date));
```

Comment: This also works perfectly, and is significantly more simple/easier to read than @ThomasDoconski's solution. I am going to use this method.  THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing enough here, you should consider a conditional aggregation

```
Declare @D Date='2022-05-20';

SELECT InvNum     = LEFT(LINEITEM.InventoryNumber, 3)
      ,DayCount   = sum( case when DateCreated = @D then 1 else 0 end ) 
      ,MonthCount = sum( case when month(DateCreated) = month(@D) then 1 else 0 end ) 
      ,YearCount  = sum( case when year(DateCreated) = year(@D) then 1 else 0 end ) 
 FROM  INVOICE
INNER JOIN  LINEITEM ON INVOICE.InvoiceID = LINEITEM.InvoiceID
WHERE InventoryNumber IS NOT Null
  AND InventoryNumber <> 'Misc'
  AND DateCreated >= format(@D,'yyyy-01-01')
GROUP BY LEFT(LINEITEM.InventoryNumber, 3)
ORDER BY InvNum ASC;
```

Comment: John,  This is getting very close to what I am looking for. When I put this in, I am getting the columns just like I want, but the day/month/year counts are not adding up correctly. I have never used declare statements, or case statements, so I am not exactly sure where/what to change on this.

Comment: This solution is clean and do the work if you set the ```@D``` to the start of the year or 365 days before, what do you better. @Lzypenguin 
It also solves the counts with no data.

Comment: Looks like OP wants results based on three different start dates: yesterday, last month, last year

Comment: @Charlieface Perhaps... without a more robust example or requirements, I was guessing at Day, Month-To-Date, and Year-To-Date

Answer (score 1):

This maybe will do the work for you:

```
SELECT ISNULL(DailyQuery.InvNum, ISNULL(MonthlyQuery.InvNum, YearlyQuery.InvNum)) as InvNum,
       ISNULL(DailyCount,0) as DailyCount,
       ISNULL(MonthlyCount,0) as MonthlyCount,
       ISNULL(YearlyCount,0) as YearlyCount
FROM
(SELECT 
    LEFT(LINEITEM.InventoryNumber, 3) AS InvNum, 
    COUNT(*) AS DailyCount
FROM
    INVOICE
INNER JOIN  
    LINEITEM ON INVOICE.InvoiceID = LINEITEM.InvoiceID
WHERE InventoryNumber != 'Misc'
    AND DateCreated > DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0,  GETDATE()-1), 0) --first hour day before
GROUP BY 
    LEFT(LINEITEM.InventoryNumber, 3)
) DailyQuery
FULL JOIN 
(SELECT 
    LEFT(LINEITEM.InventoryNumber, 3) AS InvNum, 
    COUNT(*) AS MonthlyCount
FROM
    INVOICE
INNER JOIN  
    LINEITEM ON INVOICE.InvoiceID = LINEITEM.InvoiceID
WHERE InventoryNumber != 'Misc'
    AND DateCreated > DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), 0) --first day of current month
GROUP BY 
    LEFT(LINEITEM.InventoryNumber, 3) ) MonthlyQuery ON DailyQuery.InvNum = MonthlyQuery.InvNum
FULL JOIN 
(SELECT 
    LEFT(LINEITEM.InventoryNumber, 3) AS InvNum, 
    COUNT(*) AS YearlyCount 
FROM
    INVOICE
INNER JOIN  
    LINEITEM ON INVOICE.InvoiceID = LINEITEM.InvoiceID
WHERE InventoryNumber != 'Misc'
    AND DateCreated > DATEADD(year, DATEDIFF(year, 0, GETDATE()), 0) --first day of current month
GROUP BY 
    LEFT(LINEITEM.InventoryNumber, 3) ) YearlyQuery ON MonthlyQuery.InvNum = YearlyQuery.InvNum
```

Comment: Your solution is starting to look like what I was going for, but the counts are not correct. Several of the Month counts are higher than the year counts.

Comment: You'll probably need to change the inner dates on the subquerie to what you prefer. I used fixed parameter based on dates calculated by SQL SERVER. Try changing the ```DateCreated > ...```

Comment: There was a typo in my query. Try again.

Comment: THIS WORKS.  Super long and hard for me to fully understand everything thats going on it, but it 100%. Your AND DateCreated > DATEADD line was causing the totals to not match my sample data using (5-20-2022, 4-20-2022, and 5-20-2021 as my sample hard coded dates). I do not fully understand the DATEADD part either.

Answer (score 0):

you need to write three queries each query results in these tables based on the column and date in the where clause

just change the column and date value in the where clause for each table

first query result

```
InvNum | DayCount 
abc    | 2        
def    | 0        
xyz    | 0
```

second query result:

```
InvNum  | MonthCount
abc     | 10        
def     | 2          
xyz     | 0
```

third query result:

```
InvNum | YearCount
abc    | 40
def    | 6
xyz    | 2
```

and then join these three tables on InvNum column

Comment: You'll probably want to check non ocurrencies of counts between queries using a LEFT or FULL OUTER JOIN, to show the zero ocurrencies properly.

Comment: I am not sure how I can write 3 separate queries then join them together.  Once I move on from one query to the next, the results from the first are gone... I need this all to be in one query, right?

Comment: yes, you need to have all of them in one query